# How to pass all class variables from a parent *instance* to a child class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, parent, instance-variables

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
class Parent():
    def __init__():
        self.parent_var = 'ABCD'
        x = Child(self)    # self would be passing this parent instance

class Child():
    def __init__(<some code to pass parent>):
        print(self.parent_var)

foo = Parent()
```

Now I know what you're thinking, why not just pass parent_var itself to the child instance? Well my actual implementation has over 20 class variables in Parent. I don't want to have to manually pass each variable to the __init__ of the Child instance that's instantiated in Parent-- is there a way to make all Parent class variables available to Child?

EDIT - SOLVED:
This is the way I found that works:

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent_var = 'ABCD'  # but there are 20+ class vars in this class, not just one
        x = Child(self)           # pass this parent instance to child        

class Child():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        for key, val in vars(parent).items():
            setattr(self, key, val)

        print(self.parent_var)  # successfully prints ABCD


foo = Parent()
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. `self` is one name used for two separate parameters, in `Parent.__init__` and `Child.__init__`. The signature should just be `def __init__(self)` in *both* classes.

Comment: `parent_var` is not a class variable, it's an instance variable. You need to be more precise with terminology, as the question stands it is confusing. Best you add some input / expected output so it becomes clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: `Child(self)` calls (eventually) `Child.__init__` with the current value of `self`, an instance of `parent`, as the value of the *second* parameter. Which means (sorry) the signature of `Child.__init__` should be something like `def __init__(self, obj)`; `obj` will be the instance of `Parent` passed to the call.

Comment: see my edit. I have found a solution that does what I want. Please let me know if there's a better way of doing this!

Comment: The "solution" you posted won't even run; `Parent()` will raise a `TypeError` because `Parent.__init__` doesn't define any parameters, and it will be called with at least one.

Comment: And if you fix that, you get *another* `TypeError` because `Child.__init__` is defined to take one argument, but you are passing two.

Comment: To add to the discussion of terminology, the terms "parent" and "child", and the notion of inheritance (which you've tagged your question with) have specific meaning in object oriented programming, and you're not using them in the normal ways. Ollie's answer below uses actual inheritance, if that's actually what you want (but it seems not). A lot of programming is learning how to *communicate* about computer programs, as that's not a trivial thing!

Comment: @chepner I forgot the self argument in the solution code. Fixed it. I hadn't actually copied and pasted the pseudo code and ran it. But I just did, and confirmed it works the way I want it to.

Comment: @Blckknght I understand. I am familiar with inheritance in the sense of Ollie's answer. But whereas that was inheriting a class, I wanted to "inherit" the _instance_ of a class, ie all of its instance variables. I didn't really know what to call this, but since it had to do with passing things between parent and children, I assumed it would also be called "inheritance". Sorry if that was a misleading tag!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you inherit from the parent class all variables will be present in child classes. Use super init in the child to make sure the parent class instantiates.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent_var = 'ABCD'

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

child = Child()
print(child.parent_var)
```

prints:

`'ABCD'`

Comment: If `Child.__init__` does nothing except call `super().__init__`, you can omit the definition entirely. If `Child.__init__` isn't defined, then `Parent.__init__` will be used instead.

Comment: I'm trying ton instantiate the Parent, and create a Child from within the Parent. I've found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You would pass the instance of `Parent` like you would any value.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent_var = 'ABCD'
        x = Child(self)

class Child:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        print(obj.parent_var)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution and wanted to post the answer in case anyone who finds this needs it:

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent_var = "ABCD"  # just an example
        x = Child(self)           # pass this parent instance (this object) to child        

class Child():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        # copies variables from passed-in object to this object
        for key, val in vars(parent).items():
            setattr(self, key, val)

        print(self.parent_var)  # successfully prints ABCD


foo = Parent()
```